# Blender 3.0 Crashes on render in cycles if I focus on another window

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I open a scene. I hit render with cycles, renders fine but if i move my mouse to another monitor and focus on another window, i come back to close the rendered image, and it crashes. every time.